# Input info 2x2 Array

Tags: java, arrays, object, applet

Im trying to input data on a 2x2 array, i cant use a "for" because the use of buttons, the first and second place are ok but something is wrong when i go to the next dimension of the array (the j, i guess) i would appreciate some help, thx :)

```
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == btingreso){
                if (i<c1.length)
                    if (j<c1[i].length){
                        c1[i][j]= new compu_partes (txtnombre.getText(),Integer.parseInt(txtcantidad.getText()),txtcodigo.getText(),Double.parseDouble(txtprecio.getText()));
                            i++;
                    }
                    j++;
                    i=0;
            }
}
```

Comment: you're missing brackets

Comment: what's the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your indentation! It suggests that the 2nd `if`-block also includes `j++;` and `i=0;`, which these two statements are **not**.

Also I think you incremented your indices slighly wrong.

This should work:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == btingreso){
        if (i<c1.length){
            if (j < c1[i].length){
                c1[i][j] = new compu_partes(...);
                j++;
            }
            if (j == c1[i].length){
                i++;
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```